# How should I secure an unused wire in my breaker panel?

Tags: 240v, neutral

I accidentally pulled 6-4 wiring to a machine that only needs 240 and no neutral. What to do with the white wire?

I read [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/51455/what-should-i-do-with-the-white-wire-when-wiring-a-240-volt-garage-heater) that at the machine, I just cap the white wire.  When I go to connect the wires in the main breaker panel, do I still connect the white wire to the neutral bus, or do I cap it in the panel as well?

Comment: best to connect at breaker panel  ..... or cap at breaker panel also and label both ends with a reference to the other end being capped ... local electrical code is the final judge.

Comment: Is the breaker for the circuit a two-pole common-trip breaker (the common case), or something else (such as two one-pole breakers linked by a handle tie)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The typical 50 amp, two pole breaker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cap it at both ends. If you're using a wire nut, also tape the nut on, they have trouble sticking to single wires.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes this a better idea than, say, grounding it in the panel and capping it at equipment? Is there a security and/or code issue?

Comment: It can't flow unexpected current if it's not tied to anything. It also can't violate code for wire colors.  Imagine a white wire landed on a ground bus. Next guy needs a neutral,  it rings out good, he uses it, gives it no further thought. It's on the ground bus.  If you land it on a bus, land it correctly or not at all.

Answer (score 4):

### Land it on the neutral bus

Since you have the correct breaker in there for a mixed 120/240VAC circuit, simply land the white wire on the panel neutral bus -- this way, it'll be readily available for someone in the future who wishes to repurpose this circuit.